# Visual Studio Professional 2012 uninstallation stuck

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-10, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2012 (I have 2015 now) on Windows 10, but it's stuck on "Applying: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Minimum)." The second loading bar is almost full and won't go higher. I left my laptop on overnight so it could uninstall yet it's still here.

[image: Here's what it looks like to show what I'm talking about.]

Comment: Hi Pete, does your issue is solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall the VS 2012, you can check this: [How to uninstall Visual Studio 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2771441#bookmark-force) and it describes the manual removal and forcibly uninstall methods. You can first uninstall the main product like VS 2012 professional, then uninstall the other supporting products that may be installed.

Make sure you uninstall the VS 2012 professional by the administrator account and if the manual removal failed, you can try to forcibly uninstall through the command: **vs_professional.exe /uninstall /force**. It can forcibly remove almost all components and for the detail information, you can have a look at [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/).
If the uninstall still failed, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: I solved this issue not too long ago, but I can't remember how I did it. Thanks anyway!